# how to intiialize two firebase apps

Tags: javascript, firebase

im trying to initialize two firebase apps but getting an annoying error  Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app). Im not sure how to fix this and how to make two seperate firebase. Any help is greatly appreciated!

database instance

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

 var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC....",
    authDomain: "car-app-506db.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://car-app-506db.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "car-app-506db",
    storageBucket: "car-app-506db.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "496521253390"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
export const CarsRef = databaseRef.child("Cars");
export const authRef = firebase.auth();
export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export const timeRef = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

export default databaseRef;
```

auth instance

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC6C-8A-vfsEzv31acwjhru8N64g0Hzhcc",
    authDomain: "car-app-506db.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://car-app-506db.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "car-app-506db",
    storageBucket: "car-app-506db.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "496521253390"
};



var app = firebase.initializeApp(app);
export default app;
```

Comment: What is the specific case for which you need two instances? Judging by the fact your config is the same for both, you should be ok with only one, which you can use to connect to different services.

Answer (score 4):

Each `FirebaseApp` instance has its own configuration and its own unique name. If you don't specify a name when you initialize the app, Firebase assumes your (re)initializing the default app. Since neither if your calls to `firebase.initializeApp` specifies a name, you're initializing the same app twice, which is an error.

The solution is to name your apps by passing a name (string) in to the second call to `initializeApp`. For example:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC6C-8A-vfsEzv31acwjhru8N64g0Hzhcc",
    authDomain: "car-app-506db.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://car-app-506db.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "car-app-506db",
    storageBucket: "car-app-506db.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "496521253390"
};



var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "auth");
export default app;
```

Also see [using multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application) in the Firebase docs.