# Embed firebase based app on another website

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We're building a React SDK and would like to use Firebase Realtime Database for data storage and realtime sync.

It looks like Firebase only supports *one* user to be logged in at a given time. Which means if we go with this approach, and the client app that is integrating with our SDK also uses Firebase, it won't work - as the SDK Firebase auth would clash with the underlying apps Firebase auth.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of a FirebaseApp object supports only one user signed in at a time.  You could initialize a second FirebaseApp instance (give it a name, don't take the "default") to connect to a different project and sign in another user account.

See also:

- [how to intiialize two firebase apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521001/how-to-intiialize-two-firebase-apps)
- [How to initialize multiple firebase projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679880/how-to-initialize-multiple-firebase-projects)
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/app.md#initializeapp